# Can't reinstall Google Drive App on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, google-drive

I'm on a Windows 11 Machine.  Recently there was some sort of update and after that update some of the file connections to my Google Drive Desktop app installation seem to have broken.  I couldn't uninstall using the standard methods so I started to delete the program manually.  I did the following:

##### Removed Remaining Google Drive Files:

- C:\Program Files\Google\Drive
- C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Google\Drive
- C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Google\Drive

##### Registry Cleanup:

- Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
- Type regedit and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Drive and delete the Drive folder.
- Also, check HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Google\Drive and delete the Drive folder.

After making these changes, I restarted my computer to ensure any lingering processes were terminated.

After all of this I'm still getting this pop-up window when run the Windows Google Drive app installation .exe file from here: https://www.google.com/drive/download/

[image: Google Drive already installed pop-up window]

Has anyone else run into this?  How can I fix this issue?

I Asked ChatGPT and it suggested I try to reinstall it in Safe Mode.  When I restart my computer in safe mode, I get to this PIN screen, but it won't let me setup the pin or get past this screen.  I've tried running in safe mode with and without internet connection.  Are there any ideas for how do deal with that so I can try to reinstall in safe mode
[image: Something happened and you PIN isnt available]

Comment: You don’t indicate you run the installer to remove Google Drive so you can reinstall it.